# Select - do not change diaplay value for keyup and keydown evens but trigger change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function(){
  $(".cls_user_details select").keyup(function(){
        $(".cls_user_details select").val("Profile");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cls_user_settings cls_user_details">
        <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
           <option Selected>Profile</option>
           <option value="a.php">a</option>
           <option value="b.php">b</option>
           <option value="c.php">c</option>
       </select>
       </div>
```

I am not able to achieve this. I just want to enablekeyup and keydown event but not change value. But trigger change event

Comment: If you want the change event to still fire and that event causes you to navigate away from the current page, then why do you care what the select displays, since you won't be on that page any longer?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Goos point. I am using this as settings menu. Instead `li` i am using select. So I dont want to show the changes to user. I meant up and down movements

Comment: I still don't understand, if the user is going to pick a setting that causes the page to be replaced by another page, why do you need to worry about the visible value changing? The document will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just played around with a jsfiddle to see what Chrome's capabilities are around the select element and the keyup and keydown events for the arrow keys.

As far as I can tell, here are the capabilities and limits of the keyup and keydown events for select element's when they have focus...

- keydown event:

  - Select element's menu is not open:

    - Pressing up will trigger
    - Pressing down will trigger
    - Pressing any other key will trigger
  - Select element's menu is open:

    - Pressing up will not trigger
    - Pressing down will not trigger
    - Pressing any other key will not trigger
- keyup event:

  - Select element's menu is not open:

    - Pressing up will not trigger
    - Pressing down will not trigger
    - Pressing any other key will not trigger
  - Select element's menu is open:

    - Pressing up will not trigger
    - Pressing down will not trigger
    - Pressing any other key will not trigger

Comment: Ok. If menu is open, these events dont work. Is there any work around? Any usggestions?

Comment: I can think of a few things I might try, but they're all heavily dependent on exactly what I was hoping to achieve. I'm afraid I'm not confident I am 100% sure what your end requirement is, so it's hard to say. It may also depend on the amount of time and energy you have to work on the problem. A custom-implemented select interface implemented in JavaScript is an option, for example, but that might cost way too much time and energy to be practical.